# Unclear point in derivation of action-value function

Tags: reinforcement-learning, sutton-barto

I did not understand how third equality follows from the second equality. Could some expert explain?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As $q_{\pi}(s,a)$ is defined in S&B RL book as follows:

> we define the value of taking action a in state s under a policy $\pi$, denoted $q_{\pi}(s,a)$, as the expected return starting from $s$, taking the action $a$, and thereafter following policy $\pi$

Therefore similar to state value, your highlighted step here is trying to represent your action value's $\mathbb{E}_{\pi}[G_{t+1}|S_t=s,A_t=a]$ component by the state values of all possible entering states $s'$ after taking action $a$ following the same policy $\pi$ thereafter. As for the other component involving $R_{t+1}$ you've probably already known it's only determined by the environment under above conditions.